# je to jne in assembly

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I am disassembling a code which has the following je function:

`0F 84 FF 00 00 00` : `je loc_00000105`

I am instructed to bypass the compare function by modifying `je` to `jne`. This is a weird case because everywhere i experienced this:

`74 F1` : `jne loc_fffffff3`

Which i can easily change by changing `74` to `75`:

`75 F1` : `jne loc_fffffff3`

But i am really confused how can i change:

`0F 84 FF 00 00 00` : `je loc_00000105` to `jne`

Any help will be appreciated!

I tried Changing :

`0F` to `0E`

`0F` to `0B`

etc...

Comment: "Assembly language" is a *type* of language; which one (i.e. for which processor) is this?

Comment: You can review an [instruction set reference](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_146.html) . If you go down the list you'll discover you want 0x84 changed to 0x85.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`74` is the x86 short `je` opcode, and `0F 84` is the near `je` opcode.

So this `je` -> `jne` short jump opcode patch:

`74` -> `75`

Would be equivalent to these `je` -> `jne` near jump opcodes.

`0F 84` -> `0F 85`

Here are some opcode tables for reference:

- x86: http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html
- x86_64: http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html

Comment: Thanks! it works, but from where do you convert these?

Comment: @user5954712 I just look up an x86 ASM instructions references.

Comment: I'm not your downvoter, but possibly someone might have considered some reference beneficial?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a nice x86 instruction set reference for you:

http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html

The 74 XX and 75 XX instruction encodings are JE and JNE with a 8-bit relative offset for the jump target.

0F 85 XX XX XX XX is the instruction encoding for JNE with a 32 bit offset that follows .

The corresponding JE instruction is 0F 84 XX XX XX XX.

Comment: Please do correct your answer! Get the numbers right.